# Ionic2 Angular2 error - Cannot read property 'setElementStyle' of undefined

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic2

I am trying to create a simple todo app using ionic2, I followed a tutorial [here](http://www.joshmorony.com/build-a-todo-app-from-scratch-with-ionic-2-video-tutorial/), I was trying to extend it by adding some more features like, mark as done, delete, show list of completed items etc.

I am able to mark only one item as completed but after that when i try to swipe another item to mark as done it throws a error `"Cannot read property 'setElementStyle' of undefined"`.

Below is the function throwing error,

```
  markDone(index:number){
   this.items[index].isDone = true;
   this.dataService.save(this.items);
  }
```

if i remove `this.items[index].isDone = true;` remove this line everything works fine, but item isnt getting marked as done as usual.

You can browse complete code here [on github](https://github.com/amitpatil321/Ionic2-ToDo)

Comment: This looks like its happening because you are changing the array and the index stays the same. The let i = index; part. So you are trying to display a non existant item

Comment: Ohh ok, i guess now i have to add "id" property to each todo, any other easy way ??

Comment: @misha130 : btw i am not changing the array, i am just adding a property "isDone = true", so index should remains same. So i think this isnt the problem. isnt it ?

Comment: I might've miss read the code but aren't you activating remove somehow too?

Comment: Remove functionality works fine. Even if i fresh start and without removing any item i just try to mark done any item second time i see that error.

Comment: This is really making me crazy now, instead of index i am now using "id" property to track them, but still i am getting same error :(

Comment: Found the problem. *ngIf= "!item.isDone" switch the ngif to hidden. Ngif deletes the element

Comment: switch the ngif to hidden? Sorry didnt get you do you mean instead of ngif use ngshow and nghide :(

Comment: Instead of *ngIf do [hidden] and reverse the boolean check

Comment: Yeh already googled [hidden], Thank you so much friend for the answer, i would have never able to find that issue without you. Please rewrite your answer as answer instead of comment so i can accept it as answer.